# ScheduledExecutorService is stop working after two times

Tags: android, scheduledexecutorservice

i have a `ScheduledExecutorService` in my application to log something every 10 second, but after two times its stop and i don't know why.
i have the same in my another fragment and its work fine. but this One is stop after two times.

can any body Help me and say why its stop working

here is my codes.

```
    public void getInterpreterCountService() {

    //create new scheduler to repeat
    scheduleTaskExecutor2 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    // This schedule a runnable task every 10 second
    scheduleTaskExecutor2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "run:");
        }
    }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

i called that method in onCreate of my fragment